# Converting days/hours/minutes/seconds to hours/minutes/seconds

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a timesheet application that shows how many hours were worked within a given timespan. It works perfectly but when I want to display to total hours worked it shows me this format after 24 hours have been worked: 1.01:06:16. I need to convert this to this format: 25:06:16. I searched but only found every other conversion but not the one I need The table "timespan" is in TIME format. Here is my code:

```
ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"select timespan as 'Temps' from shopmanager.time_sheet where project_number = @project_number and users_employee_number = @users_employee_number and week_number = @week_number;", con);    

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_number", username.default_project);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@users_employee_number", username.user_id);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week_number", GetWeekNumber());
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            object sum;
            sum = dt.Compute("Sum(Temps)", "");
            textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

Being new to this, I can't seem to figure it out. If someone could help me out, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please change `textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();` to `textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
            var bob = sum.GetType(); cmd.Parameters.Clear();` What is the value of `bob`?

Comment: Your `TimeSpan.Parse` may be unnecessary. If you can make the change I suggested and check the value of `bob` we can show you a better and faster way of solving the issue. Also, by providing this information this helps the **next** person who has this issue.

Comment: Ok thank you. I’ll give it a shot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. Here is the final code:

```
object sum;
            sum = dt.Compute("Sum(Temps)", "");
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(sum.ToString());
            string timeForDisplay = (int)time.TotalHours + time.ToString(@"\:mm\:ss");
            textBox1.Text = timeForDisplay;
```

That works perfectly.